# Bundle sounds not working on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I'm testing my app in the iOS simulator, on iOS 6, but the sounds included in my bundle, which work fine on a device, are not found on the simulator. Is this a common problem?

Comment: reset simulator, do clean build and try again.

Comment: Check system volume and speaker sound

Answer (score 1):

Existing files are stored in your simulator so

**Reset your simulator**

```
iOS simulator -> Reset Content and Settings
```

Now `clean` and `run`..

Answer (score 0):

You should not worry much about the sound for your simulator. Its best if its working on a real device.

Still you can just Reset your simulator. Check your system volume and speaker volume.

Clean and build your code.

It will work fine.